# How to kick off multiple R processes listening on the same port?

Tags: r, plumber

I have an R script that is exposed as a HTTP end point via Plumber.

How can I setup multiple processes of the same script running on the same port so that I can scale it up to carry a higher load? Currently I am spawning the HTTP process as below.

```
startWebListener <- function(modelName, httpPort) {
  r <- plumb(modelName)
  r$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = httpPort)
}
```

The script is being run on a linux server and being kicked off in PM2 as

```
pm2 -f start --interpreter="Rscript" <path>
```

Thanks!